# Why are YouTube videos using 'youtube.com/v' not loading

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Please review [this page](http://www.islandcricket.lk/videos/sri-lanka/cricket/it-feels-great-mathews-talks-about-test-series-victory-against-australia).

The embedded video plays when the page is viewed on a mobile device but not when viewed on a computer (tested on two laptops running Windows 8 and 10, on Chrome, FF, and Edge).

This issue only exists with YouTube videos and the problem began 48 hours ago (approx.)

For example, see this YouTube URL (no video is being loaded):

http://www.youtube.com/v/RCsJHHUkisw&rel=0&color1=0x054b81&color2=0xe2e2e2&hd=1&showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&fs=1

Comment: Welcome to stack please review this page http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What on that page do you want me to review?

Comment: Is there something preventing you from switching to /embed? Using /v forces the Flash player, which is deprecated.

Comment: The video module used for the CMS uses this method, so I am forced to stick with it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to handle this problem by rewriting the emvideo module.

I am currently using the module version = "6.x-1.26".

I didn’t take the time to change the entire module;
I changed only the parts I needed:

All the changes were made in this file:
\sites\all\modules\emfield\contrib\emvideo\providers\youtube.inc

1. In `function theme_emvideo_youtube_flash` line 444 I changed the line

   `$url = check_plain("http://www.youtube.com/v/$code&$related$autoplay_value$colors$border$high_quality$display_info$enablejsapi$fs");`

   to
   `$url = check_plain("https://www.youtube.com/embed/$code");` .

What I did was to look at the youtube embed code and try to make the link look the same.

2. Next step was to change the FLASH output, in line 566 function
   `theme_emvideo_youtube_default_external` and change the next content:

`<div id="$div_id">
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="$height" width="$width" data="$url" id="$id">
          <param name="movie" value="$url" />
          <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain"/>
          <param name="quality" value="best"/>
          <param name="allowFullScreen" value="$fullscreen_value"/>
          <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"/>
          <param name="scale" value="noScale"/>
          <param name="salign" value="TL"/>
          <param name="FlashVars" value="$flashvars" />
          <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        </object>
</div>`

To

`<div id="$url"><iframe width="$width" height="$width" src="$url" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>`

And that’s all…

Hope it helps a bit…

Answer (score 3):

The following should be pretty close to a drop-in replacement for what's currently being served on [the page referenced in the question](http://www.islandcricket.lk/videos/sri-lanka/cricket/it-feels-great-mathews-talks-about-test-series-victory-against-australia) (the `object` tag with id `emvideo-youtube-flash-2`):

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="590" height="499"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Je2vE5RLJ6o?rel=1&showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1&fs=1&origin=http://www.islandcricket.lk/"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

A few things about the implementation currently being served:

- Using `object` tag and the embed URLs of the form youtube.com/v/`video id` (which only serves a Flash player, not HTML5) to embed YouTube videos [has been deprecated for over a year](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference).
- the player parameter `hd` [is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#hd).  The iFrame player (used in the above code), will automatically chose the best quality to display based on a variety of parameters.  If you wish to control this you can [use the Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#setPlaybackQuality).
- the `rel`, `showinfo`, `enablejsapi` and `fs` parameters should continue to function as they have in the previous implementation ([parameter documentaion here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters))
- The `allowScriptAcess` parameter set to `sameDomain` in the current implementation is replaced by the `origin` parameter and should be set to the URL severing the webpage ([documented here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#origin))

Screenshot of the above code working on islandcricket.lk tested via webdev tools:[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, matthewayne! I do not know how to implement the above in the module I am using. 

There is a file within the module I am using (youtube.inc), which I think can be altered so that video renders correctly, but not sure how to post it here.

Comment: This issue does not exist when these links are viewed on a mobile device.

Comment: Do you have a URL/webpage for the module you're using?

Comment: If I'm reading the page correctly, it looks like this module hasn't been updated in 9 years.  It might be good to look into another module or implementing DavSev rewrite in his answer.