# API using youtube.googleapis.com seems broken

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Since couple of days, youtube.googleapis.com seems completely broken.

Until that moment, embedding video, like https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/dQw4w9WgXcQ worked with no problem. Right now, Player seems to be completely broken on chrome, firefox, and any device I can put my hands on.

Is there something I'm not knowning that is obvious, or is there some great conspiracy on the subject?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are YouTube videos using 'youtube.com/v' not loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917194/why-are-youtube-videos-using-youtube-com-v-not-loading)

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue. It seems that to embed videos, we have to use this format, with "embed".

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/We1o204XYGw?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I think they may have depreciated the other format.
Which leaves me with hundreds of misformed videos on my site!